# How do I generate predicted counts from a negative binomial regression with a logged independent variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a set of data with a dependent variable that is a count, and several independent variables.  My primary independent variable is large dollar values.  If I divide the dollar values by 10,000(to keep the coefficients manageable), the models(negative binomial and zero-inflated negative binomial) run in Stata and I can generate predicted counts with confidence intervals.  However, theoretically it is more logical to take the natural log of this variable.  When I do that, the models still run but now predicted counts on range between 0.22-0.77 or so.  How do I fix this so the predicted counts generate correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not show any code or data. It's nearly impossible to know what is going wrong without these two ingredients. Your questions reads as "I did some stuff to this other stuff with surprising results." *In order to ask a good question, you should replicate your coding approach with a dataset that everyone would have access to*, like rod93.

Here's my attempt at that, which shows reasonably similar predictions with `nbreg` from both models:

```
webuse rod93, clear
replace exposure = exposure/10000

nbreg deaths exposure age_mos, nolog
margins
predictnl d1 =predict(n), ci(lb1 ub1)
/* Compare the prediction for the first obs by hand */
di exp(_b[_cons]+_b[age_mos]*age_mos[1]+_b[exposure]*exposure[1])
di d1[1]

gen ln_exp = ln(exposure)
nbreg deaths ln_e age_mos, nolog
margins
predictnl d2 =predict(n), ci(lb2 ub2)
/* Compare the prediction for the first obs by hand */
di exp(_b[_cons]+_b[age_mos]*age_mos[1]+_b[ln_e]*ln(exposure[1]))
di d2[1]
sum d? lb* ub*, sep(2)
```

This produces very similar predictions and confidence intervals:

```
. sum d? lb* ub*, sep(2)

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
          d1 |         21    84.82903    25.44322   12.95853   104.1868
          d2 |         21     85.0432    25.24095   32.87827   105.1733
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         lb1 |         21    64.17752    23.19418   1.895858   80.72885
         lb2 |         21    59.80346    22.01917    10.9009   79.71531
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
         ub1 |         21    105.4805    29.39726   24.02121   152.7676
         ub2 |         21    110.2829    29.16468   51.76427    143.856
```